# C# MVC3 ViewBag, how to use lists property in view within foreach statement?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

```
public class RegisterSubscription
{
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int SubscrSelected { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; }
        public string InfoUrl { get; set; }
}

private List<RegisterSubscription> activePlans = new List<RegisterSubscription>();
```

In my controller I have **ViewBag.ActivePlans = activePlans;** and the ViewBag fills with the correct data. Now in my view I have:

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.ActivePlans)
{
    <li class="popupmenu" id="service_@(item.ID)" >
    <div>
    @Html.Image(item.Image, new { style="border-style:none; text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; width:64px; height:64px" })
    </div>
    </li>
}
```

but I get the following error: 
'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' has no applicable method named 'Image' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.

Any help will be greatly appreciated,
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Warning: I haven't done any MVC stuff, so this is guesswork.

My guess is that ActivePlans is dynamic in some form... so you basically need to make `item` strongly typed. It *may* be just as simple as this:

```
@foreach (RegisterSubscription item in ViewBag.ActivePlans)
```

... which would basically cast each item to `RegisterSubscription` as it got it out of the `ViewBag`. After that point, I can't see that you've got anything dynamic, so the extension method should be okay. I think. Maybe. When the wind is right.

Comment: @Jon Skeet - what if I am using an anonymous type. Ex. ViewBag.ActivePlans = new { Prop = "Value" }`? How could I access `ActivePlans.Prop` from the view without being able to cast the object? Possible at all?

Comment: @one.beat.consumer: I don't know, to be honest.

Comment: @JonSkeet thank you for the quick reply. my guess is i cannot. i went ahead and made a quick view model but was trying to avoid that